# Django template for loop iterating two item

Tags: django, templates, for-loop

I try to implement a forloop in Django tempalte iterating two items per cycle such that

```
{% for c in cList%}
<ul class="ListTable">
    <li>
         {{ c1.name }}
    </li>
    <li>
         {{ c2.name }}
    </li>

</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

I know my code is not a proper way to do that but I couldn't find anyway.
I really appreciate for any suggestion

Thanks

Comment: Is each item in cList itself an array? Where do the 2 items c1, c2 come from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can control the list structure that is `cList`, why don't you just make it a list of tuples of 2 elements or a list of list of 2 elements, like

```
#in the view
cList = [(ob1, ob2), 
         (ob3, ob4)]
```

and the in the template

```
{% for c1, c2 in cList %}

 <ul class="ListTable">
   <li>
     {{ c1.name }}
   </li>
   <li>
      {{ c2.name }}
   </li>
</ul>
 {% endfor %}
```

Also you can use the `zip` function to facilitate the creation of cList, or define a 
function which create that kind of structure from a list of objects, like

```
def pack(_list):
    new_list = zip(_list[::2], _list[1::2])
    if len(_list) % 2:
        new_list.append((_list[-1], None))
    return new_list
```

Comment: side question, what does the double colon `::` mean in the slice

Comment: [START:END:JUMP] so `[::] == [0:-1:1]`

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use the the built-in template tag [cycle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle)

and do something like:

```
{% for c in c_list %}
    {% cycle True False as row silent %}

    {% if row %}
        <ul class="ListTable">
    {% endif %}

        <li>
             {{ c.name }}
        </li>

    {% if not row or forloop.last %}
        </ul>    
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Note: if you have odd number of element on the list the last table will have only one element with this option, sice we are checking for `forloop.last`

Comment: This answer is so underrated!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to implement cyraxjoe solution which does work, but theres only one problem with it...

a = [1,2,3] will return [(1,2)] but will remove the 3.

So i was asking around in irc freenode #python for a solution and i got this:

```
it = iter(a); nested = [list(b) for b in itertools.izip_longest(it, it)]
print nested
[[1, 2], [3, None]]
```

I was also told to look up the documentation for the itertools module, and search for the "grouper" recipe. which does something similar but i havent tried it yet.

I hope this helps :)

*Credits to except and lvh from the #python channel